# Is there a way to use the same Conversation for two separate brands?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

**GOAL:**
Avoid duplicate conversations by using variables (domain-specific values) in dialogs.

**SCOPE:**
We have two different brands/domains privately in the same corporate family.
One for professionals, one for hobbyists.
The two brands **do not** wish to be publicly associated with one-another.
There is a 90% overlap in products between the two brands.  More specifically, the overlap is in product ***formulas***, but each brand has it's own naming convention.

**QUESTION:**
What would be the best way to share one IBM Watson Conversation between two brands/domains which each have their own  brand-specific product names?

For **example**, if a customer asked, "*Which product should I use for XYZ requirement?*", the Pro domain should answer "*Formula 88*" whereas the hobbyist domain should answer "*FreeFast*"
...same question, same product, two different names.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge using Watson Conversation, you can:

The reason for has *Products* and response's **different** for each Domain... You can build 2 Workspaces, each one with the domain that you want, and you can build your dialog according to the domain and your **scope**.

And with one custom code in your back-end, according to domains (the Professionals and Hobbyists), you can call the Conversation service with the workspace_id by your Chatbot built inside IBM Bluemix.

**Important:** You said that have the same products, then, you can build 2 workspaces, STEPS:

- Create the first workspace called Professionals(Or what you want for the first domain);
- Create the Entity **[@products](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities)** with ALL **Products** (Use entity for these products is a good idea)
- Create the **#[Intents](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html#defining-intents)** (what you want)
- Create the **[Dialog](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build)** with your Conversation flow
- **DUPLICATE** the workspace, CHANGE the name of duplicate for (Hobbyist) for your domain and just **CHANGE** or **ADD** the *response* for EACH **domain**
  (Professionals or Hobbyist WORKSPACE).

This idea will generate less *rework*.

- See more about [building](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build) a dialog with Watson Conversation Service.
- See the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/).